# enum attribute of model in ROR sometime have a value of nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I have a model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { requested: 0, received: 1, sent: 3 }
  validates_presence_of :status
end

def self.save_value(item_id, value
  item = Item.find(item_id)
  item.value = value
  item.save!
end
```

Sometimes (< 1% of time) I receive error like `Validation failed: status can't be blank` on `item.save!`

Points to be noted

1. Status has a default value of 0 i.e it is never blank.
2. In database status is never empty (I have checked all of the entries).

I am note sure what is problem, is that the problem of Enum?

- OS: Ubuntu
- WebServer: Puma [2 workers and 12 threads]

Comment: 1. Did you set the default value for status in your migration?

2. Where are you setting the value for the status column in your `self.save_value` method?

Comment: @mokayode yes default value has been set in migration and self.save_value is called through a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar issue now, as I analysed one reason could be if the enum hash in model is updated(i.e. some key value is removed) and there were already some records in DB with those enum values, then its set to nil.

And in such case my `Model.where(status: nil).count` or `Model.where(status: nil)` is also not fetching those records in rails console.